# Iphone Safari not accessing Springboot Controller

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, axios

Im using springboot for backend and reactjs for frontend for a small app im working on , all is working fine on all browsers except iphone safari. When my app loads up the first thing it does is an axios get command to retrieve data and this doesnt work on iphone safari. I put logs in the back end controller and these are not being hit so the issue seems to be axios -- > backend. Am wondering are there any properties i need to add to axios call specifically for safari ? or is there settings i need to set on springboot to allow requests from safaris use of axios for requests?

Comment: What response did you get from axios?

Comment: am not seeing a response coming back from axios its as if a CORS issue or something needs set in request for safari using iphone is needed am thinking, the rest of app appears as expected but any calls to the backend dont occur and using iphone i cant check the console so am thinking something unique to safari for axios as other browsers can make request and get data back

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.